# «Но» перед деепричастным оборотом — нужна запятая или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот, причастный-оборот

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после "но" в этом предложении?

"Да, от ДТП гибнет больше людей, но(,) проезжающий мимо места ДТП водитель, никогда не заразится кармой жертвы аварии".

И вообще, является ли кусок "проезжающий мимо места ДТП водитель" деепричастным оборотом?

Answer (score 4):

***Проезжающий*** не деепричастие, а причастие. Поэтому речь может идти о причастном обороте. Если предложение перестроить и определяемое слово "водитель" поставить перед причастием, то запятые будут выделять причастный оборот:

*Да, от ДТП гибнет больше людей, но водитель, проезжающий мимо места ДТП, никогда не заразится кармой жертвы аварии.*

В первоначальном предложении две последние запятые не нужны, так как причастный оборот стоит перед определяемым словом. См., например, [здесь](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/prichastie/prichastnyi-oborot-pered-opredelyaemyim-slovom-primery.html).

Если же использовать деепричастие "проезжая", то оборот следует выделить:

"..., но, проезжая мимо места ДТП, водитель..."